# Reputation notification resurfaces after a page refresh

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, top-bar

When you have new reputation activity while the "There are a few questions with new activity" bar is shown and you click on your reputation activity to watch and afterwards refresh the page, it will again show them as new. If you view them again, the notification dissapears.

Steps to reproduce:

- Have reputation activity going on
- Step away from computer for 15 minutes
- View reputation activity dropdown overview
- Close dropdown overview, verify the notification is gone
- Refresh page
- Gasp at resurfaced notification for the same reputation changes

Browser: Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m

Comment: It's not that it again shows them as new, it's that the JS doesn't clear the client cache upon real-time notification, this is planned probably today as part of a JS consolidation there.

Comment: Good to hear, thank you for the response!

Comment: Update: this will be delayed a bit.  Jarrod and I tried to make the current JS work with change yesterday and hated it, reverting changes - it was just way too hacky.  We're taking an extra day or two to re-write top topbar script the way it needs to be (think of each dropdown object-model-like), doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed a while ago, just forgot to close this out - enjoy!

Comment: Noticed it, thanks for getting back to me!