# Reputation and inbox notification shows up again after refresh

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, top-bar

This was asked before too. [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208314/reputation-notification-resurfaces-after-a-page-refresh).

Currently I am facing the issue of appearance of reputation notification in above toolbar.

I can see the reputation notification, for every page refresh even after clicking and viewing the notification.

current browser: Chrome Version 36.0.1985.143 m

Comment: Not only the reputation notifications - but also unread  inbox messages

Comment: @alfasin yeah true.. I didn't get your message notification.

Comment: Also mentioned [on meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268957/topbar-notifications-dont-go-away). Seems to be widespread.

Comment: Can't even see reputation of other users on hover on a username's link too.

Comment: Probably by design, they are testing stuff and test is not over yet.

Comment: @PatrickHofman https://www.stackstatus.net/

Comment: ShadowWizard they wrote it's a read-write test, I don't think it's relevant. Looks like they deployed a bug... @david-fullerton

Comment: There's another problem with different symptoms. I suspect that it might still be related since it also started after the site maintenance completed. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268978/review-votes-ignored-and-reviews-showing-repeatedly. I don't know if it affects sites other than SO, so I posted it on MSO.

Comment: Can you guys give it a try now please? @MonicaCellio

Comment: It's still happening to me on Seasoned Advice. The tabs are unchanged. The system obviously still adds rep points, since I just signed up for this stack and can leave this comment. But the tab still shows the number (that actually should have changed a few times today) that it's been showing since it got stuck.

Comment: @NickCraver (sorry for delay; didn't, err, see a notification...)  Still a little funky here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YInGm.png  BTW the rep shown there is a stuck value; I've already viewed that.  Addendum: I was just able to clear the rep value.  Moderator diamond remains blue after viewing.

Comment: @NickCraver: Still have the stuck notification on SO, with newer notifications not showing.

Comment: @NickCraver I'm here at the computer for the next several hours. Feel free to ping me if you need a tester, I'll open a window in the chat here. Mine is still stuck where it was at noon.

Comment: @nick: should notifications during the time the bug was there come up? I see I had an answer accepted by no notification. It doesn't show even when opening the drop down, but I see it in the reputation tab of my profile.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I just came to say *exactly* the same thing. The upvote is tallied in my total rep and shows up in my profile, but not on the drop down.

Comment: @Jol: I did get the notification from your comment though using the mobile app, but not in the browser.

Comment: @Jol: it's coming in a little later on the web. A few refreshes did it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yep, it took 2 refreshes, but I got the first one (notification), still not the second.

Comment: @alfasin I don't think it's a coincidence. Maybe they didn't intend for things to actually break but fact is, things broke.

Comment: @Jol: me too...

Comment: Have "1 unread" inbox notification stuck since yesterday (after maintenance thing).

Comment: Another issue, maybe or maybe not related. I have an email saying that I have 18 unread messages in my Stack Exchange inbox. The email is the same message, repeated 18 times. The comment was posted 2014-08-16 16:24:54Z.

Comment: Hmm Getting somewhere maybe? My notification boxes don't seem stuck anymore.

Comment: @nick, I had both Inbox and Reputation stuck on Super User. Clicking the Inbox here on Meta finally cleared that. Back on Super User, I now only see the reputation stuck; the inbox is cleared there too. Clicking the reputation shows a GET to `topbar/achievements?_=14...979` (id redacted). I guess I could do the same trick for that, but for now I didn't, in case you want me to test something. (As an aside: I was logged off while browsing Super User yesterday, and needed to use OpenID to log in, while I was actually still logged in on Stack Overflow so was kind of expecting an automatic login.)

Comment: Mine are definitely still stuck on [photography.se] and [pets.se], but I haven't seen the behaviour with notifications or the moderator diamonds yet.

Comment: I am having a stuck New reputation changes notification on different sites. I can click through to the subject of the notification (e.g. clicking the link for "+10 for BLAH"), but as soon as I click any other link, the notification is back.

Comment: In my case, it got stuck there when I tried to clear it on Anime.SE. I only manage to clear my notification by opening the list on Meta.SE.

Comment: For reference: Seems not an issue with FF31.0 on linux.

Comment: @Nick, the Inbox that was cleared by viewing it here on MSE, meanwhile has a new notification in there, which is stuck when looking at it from Super User or Stack Overflow. Same problem from a different computer on different IP address, for which I also was logged in already. (I'm leaving it there, and I have NOT done obvious things such as clearing cookies or cache, in case you want me to test something.)

Comment: Reproduced @nhahtdh's report: if I open the "stuck" notifications on other sites (in my case I tried Mi Yodeya, Writers, and Moderators) it doesn't clear them, but when I open them here on MSE they clear (on all sites where I've looked).  I'm still getting unreported rep changes (that is, things that never show up in the list there, but are in my profiles).

Comment: Am stuck with the lack of notifications on rep changes too, across all the SE sites. The problem with the unread messages seems to be over.

Comment: I wonder though about the lack of official information on the matter by now. But maybe the SE staff all have sunday.

Comment: For me, the problem resolved itself when I got another inbox message. I previously had a persistent "1 unread inbox message", which has now gone.

Comment: Yeah, seems fixed already.

Comment: Looks semi-fixed for me on SO. The stuck notifications have disappeared for both messages and old rep events. But there are no new notifications for new rep events.

Comment: I just got, and successfully dismissed from Mi Yodeya, a rep notification.

Comment: So no solution? We only hope for the sx team to fix this?

Comment: Is definitely not yet fixed on CV.

Comment: @Nick, fixed for me. (Not that I get a lot of notifications, but accidentally clicking the achievements icon on Super User made it go away, and stay away after a page refresh.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was caused by a Redis failover snafu during the maintenance on Saturday. It should be all cleaned up now, though you'll need to click the notification one last time to clear it.

Comment: Still not fixed on Area51. If I get rep change while there, it will show up every time after page reload, and only after clearing it on "ordinary" site it will stop showing. Should I submit new bug report for this?